# What is the passcode?

Tags: cipher, mystery

Another unsolved case for you to investigate.  This one concerns a robbery of very sensitive government information, along with the murder of several former government secret agents.  The CIA has captured the culprit, but they have not found any affiliations with other suspects, but you know this was not a lone wolf attack.  The only thing you have is the suspect's phone, but it is locked by a four character passcode, which is a combination of letters and numbers (not case sensitive).  Once you have found the passcode, you will be closer to finding out who else is responsible for this crime and bring them to justice.  Good luck.

What is (*)?

> Order of sequence...

Character #1: About me will tell you what you need.  It has sown the seed to what great thing? (7)

Character #2: Hiroshima and Nagasaki, for what when? (3)

Character #3: For the readers and gamers, this one's a number.  Clancy's Roy G. Biv

Character #4: Note 5 in the key of C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The passcode is

> A46G

Character 1

> In the 'About Me' section of your profile, you have the name, "General Sherman". There is a tree called the General Sherman Tree. It is a sequoia tree. The 7th letter in 'sequoia' is 'a'. 'A' is the first character of the passcode.

Character 2

> Hiroshima and Nagasaki were both bombed because of the attack on Pearl Harbor. The bombing of Pearl Harbor happened in the year 1941, and the order of sequence is 3. So Character two must be the third digit in 1941, which is 4. Character 2 is 4.

Character 3

> The clue said that this one was a number. Roy G. Biv refers to the rainbow, and the game that is implied by this clue is Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege. The third character of the passcode is 6.

Character 4

> The fifth note in the key of C is G. G is the fourth character of the passcode.

Answer (score 2):

1. > ?
2. > ?
3. > **6**.  Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six.
4. > **G**.

<sub>(Suggestion for the future: if you are going to do a puzzle that, as here, appears to be nothing more than a collection of disjoint things to solve, at least put them together somehow so the solver can check if their solution is correct.)</sub>